# How to display and format data using textBrowser or any other diplay widget

Tags: qt, wav

I want to display the first 40 Bytes of a WAV file in QT using textBrowser class, I created a short program that makes this possible. However, I was wondering if there is better way to format the displayed data like printf in C that gives you formatting options to your output such hex, dec, float, or adding commas, spaces, etc. If textBrowser is not a good option, more options are welcome as I know that it inherits from textEdit. My goal is that if using QT, it can be displayed the whole data in HEX or DEC without the need of using the for loop and separated by commas for example.  Thanks in advance.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    wav->setHeader(Filename);  //set the QByteArray bufffer in WAV class with first 40 bytes

    for (int i=0;i<40;i++)
    {
        unsigned char var = wav->buffer.at(i);
        ui->textBrowser->insertPlainText(QString::number(var));
        ui->textBrowser->insertPlainText(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: QT does not support C!

Comment: going through the QString Class I found the public function arg() and the static plublic member QString::number(int n, int base=16) and it helps to format the string adding spaces or commas, etc and changing the base of the number. I change the last 2 lines of the code so the ouput is HEX numbers separated by space and single numbers will be filled with 0.  `QString myString = QString::number(var,16).toUpper(); ui->textBrowser->insertPlainText(QString("%1 ").arg(myString,2,'0'));`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something like printf() then there is `QString::sprintf()`

Answer (score 0):

QString class documentation suggested to use **QString::arg()** to format your output. You can add tabs, padding chars to your answer, etc., here is the link I followed: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#arg and along with the public member **QString::number()**, it can help you to display your numbers in different number systems.